# Disabling or Enabling a Sub-item in Strip-Menu

Tags: c#, menustrip

Please, I want to disable or enable a sub item of menu strip through code. How can I do that, please?

Have a look at the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In code, set the Enable property of that menu strip to false to disable, true to enable:

```
fichierMenuStrip.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply
i want do that from anthor window form

something like this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/10486/create-menustrip-dynamically-in-C-Sharp.aspx

but i dont understand how i can acces to element that i can desable it